How does `evtest` determine the list of key events of a PS/2 keyboard?
I've got a fairly old PS/2 keyboard with 125 keys, of which some only emit scancodes, which are not tied to any keycodes. Now I'd like to start setkeycodes as a systemd service to assign keycodes to these "problematic" keys. Running evtest, however, shows me some strange keycodes, which do not correspond to any (physical) key on my board, whereas the keys F16 thru F22 (and a bunch of other keys I'm omitting here for clarity), are not mentioned at all:
Input driver version is 1.0.1
Input device ID: bus 0x11 vendor 0x1 product 0x1 version 0xab41
Input device name: "AT Translated Set 2 keyboard"
Supported events:
  Event type 0 (EV_SYN)
  Event type 1 (EV_KEY)
    Event code 1 (KEY_ESC)
    // Standard PC keycode omitted
    Event code 85 (KEY_ZENKAKUHANKAKU)
    Event code 86 (KEY_102ND)
    // F11 & F12 omitted
    Event code 89 (KEY_RO)
    Event code 90 (KEY_KATAKANA)
    Event code 91 (KEY_HIRAGANA)
    Event code 92 (KEY_HENKAN)
    Event code 93 (KEY_KATAKANAHIRAGANA)
    Event code 94 (KEY_MUHENKAN)
    Event code 95 (KEY_KPJPCOMMA)
    Event code 96 (KEY_KPENTER)
    // Arrow keys omitted
    Event code 122 (KEY_HANGUEL)
    Event code 123 (KEY_HANJA)
    Event code 124 (KEY_YEN)
    // Meta & compose keys omitted
    Event code 128 (KEY_STOP)
    Event code 140 (KEY_CALC)
    Event code 142 (KEY_SLEEP)
    Event code 143 (KEY_WAKEUP)
    Event code 155 (KEY_MAIL)
    Event code 156 (KEY_BOOKMARKS)
    Event code 157 (KEY_COMPUTER)
    Event code 158 (KEY_BACK)
    Event code 159 (KEY_FORWARD)
    Event code 163 (KEY_NEXTSONG)
    Event code 164 (KEY_PLAYPAUSE)
    Event code 165 (KEY_PREVIOUSSONG)
    Event code 166 (KEY_STOPCD)
    Event code 172 (KEY_HOMEPAGE)
    Event code 173 (KEY_REFRESH)
    Event code 183 (KEY_F13)
    Event code 184 (KEY_F14)
    Event code 185 (KEY_F15)
    // Where are F16 thru F22 (#186 thru #192)?
    Event code 217 (KEY_SEARCH)
    Event code 226 (KEY_MEDIA)

How can I make the missing F keys appear on ths list? And: Do they have to be listed here at all in order to be used in setkeycodes? My O/S is OpenSuSE Leap 15.5 on AMD64.

OK, I've got it. I simply assigned the keycodes #186 thru #192 to the keys F16 thru F22 by using setkeycodes. This is the full program call, which also contains the other special keys:
sudo /usr/bin/setkeycodes 5e 183 5f 184 63 185 62 186 5d 187 6a 188 74 189 77 190 76 191 6b 192 64 112 66 116 5c 127 6c 226 71 117 75 164 68 128 67 95 6f 91 6d 85 65 157


Now all the the special keys emit valid keycodes.
